# gradient of norm square of a random vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Let $g(w)= \|Y_n - f(w,X_n) \|^2$ where $f:\Bbb R^d \times \Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^k : w \in \Bbb R^d$. What is the gradient of $g$ ? $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are random vectors.

Basically, I want to find gradient of a function like $\phi(x) = ||g(x)||^2$

where $g$ is a vector-valued function.

$$\phi(x) = \|g(x)\|^2$$

Now, 
$$\phi(x+h) = \|g(x+h)\|^2 = \|g(x) + h^TQ\|^2 = \|g(x)\|^2 + \|h^TQ\|^2 + 2\langle g(x),h^TQ\rangle.$$ How to find gradient from this ? Here $Q$ is a matrix where each column is the corresponding gradient for that co-ordinate.

I don't think with this method I can get it independent of $h$

Comment: Then do it. What's your question?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : plz reopen it.

Comment: The question will only be reopened after you have provided, in the question body, your thoughts on the question, any attempts you have made to answer the question yourself, and what part of the question you feel are causing you trouble (for instance not understanding a definition or how to apply a method).

Comment: @DanielRust: I have specified where I am stuck.

Comment: This question is fine and should be reopened.

Comment: @DanielRust: I have wrote explicitly where do I stuck. But, I think people who has much reputation should understand what someone is asking from the context (unless it is extremely trivial) rather than asking to write explicitly everything. For example, here I have not added nothing new. I guess that will be much of time save for everyone and we can discuss many more questions.

Comment: @user148951 The context that people ask for is so that people know what you've tried, and the specific issue that you're having trouble with. In general, 'do my work for me' posts are frowned upon here - but questions that actually indicate your thoughts on the problem are fine.

Comment: @user61527: I completely agree with you. My point is that a good researcher should guess what someone is asking and may be he can ask a counter question like "Are you asking this ...". I don't think putting questions on "hold" arbitrarily without any comment is a good idea.

Comment: @user148951 If your question has so few details that it can't be answered without a dialogue with users asking for clarification, then perhaps it's not ready to be asked. You shouldn't expect people to guess what you're asking....

Comment: @user61527: I think we should concentrate on the problem rather than arguing over unnecessary things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is $J(x)g(x)$. Where $J$ is the jacobian for the function $g$. This comes directly from 1st-order taylor series expansion.